# jQuery UI rails gem error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, datatables

So I'm using ruby on rails and the jquery datatable and just added the jquery-ui-rails gem as per [Rails Cast #340](http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables%20RailsCast) Did the bundle install. This is my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require_tree .
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
```

and here's my application.css file:

```
/*
 *= require jquery.ui.all
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
 */
```

I restarted my server, and again and again but this error persists:

```
couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.all'
in ...app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:13)
```

My gem versions are as follows:

```
Using rake 10.3.2
Using i18n 0.6.9
Using json 1.8.1
Using minitest 5.3.4
Using thread_safe 0.3.3
Using tzinfo 1.1.0
Using activesupport 4.1.1
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using actionview 4.1.1
Using rack 1.5.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using actionpack 4.1.1
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.4
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 4.1.1
Using activemodel 4.1.1
Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
Using activerecord 4.1.1
Using sass 3.2.19
Using bootstrap-sass 2.3.2.0
Using climate_control 0.0.3
Using cocaine 0.5.4
Using coffee-script-source 1.7.0
Using execjs 2.0.2
Using coffee-script 2.2.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.1.1
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
Using hike 1.2.3
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Using jbuilder 2.0.7
Using jquery-rails 3.1.0
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.11.0
Using sprockets-rails 2.1.3
Using sass-rails 4.0.3
Using jquery-datatables-rails 1.12.2 from git://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails.git (at master)
Using jquery-ui-rails 4.2.1
Using mysql 2.9.1
Using paperclip 4.1.1
Using bundler 1.6.2
Using rails 4.1.1
Using rdoc 4.1.1
Using sdoc 0.4.0
Using turbolinks 2.2.2
Using uglifier 2.5.0
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it... The problem is you have to move both the gem 'jquery-ui-rails' and 'jquery-datatables-rails' line outside of the asset group and bundle install. I also restarted the terminal. It works now. Unbelievable...